# How to schedule a quartz job on all 'workers'?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

So I have a quartz installation using JDBCJobStore that has multiple tomcat workers.  Is there a way to schedule a job to fire on all workers each time it is triggered?

It seems like this would be a standard request, I feel I just don't know what to search for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not how clustered Quartz works. As you probably know, the job always runs at exactly one machine and the Quartz itself decides on which one should it be executed.

I believe the easiest way to achieve what you want is to have a separate non-clustered `Scheduler` running independently on every Tomcat worker. This way each scheduler will run the same job separately.

Comment: Unfortunate, as I would think this could/would be useful in more than just my situation. Thanks.

Comment: @tomasz-nurkiewicz stated "This way each scheduler will run the same job separately". If they are separate non-clustered schedulers how would they run the same Job? Wouldn't you need a job on for each scheduler scheduled?

Comment: @km1: that's correct, you must schedule the same job to fire at the same time on each node separately. This is a poor workaround, but kind-of works.

Answer (score 0):

One other possibility is to create multiple instances of the scheduled job by, for example, using a group id that incorporates the hostname, when you register the job with the quartz scheduler. This way, each machine in the cluster will have it's own unique instance of the scheduled job that it and only it will run when the trigger fires. Hope this helps.