# Multiple Quartz schedulers to run same job

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I searched around looking for my situation but found many threads on making multiple quartz schedulers on different machines run a job once. My situation is the opposite. We have multiple web servers behind a load balancer, all are using quartz and connect to the same database. One of the jobs is to load log files from a third party app into the database. When the job is triggered only one of the web servers picks it up. I am trying to find a solution to have one scheduled job and when it is triggered all the attached web servers will pick it up and start processing the logs on that machine from this third party app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to schedule a quartz job on all 'workers'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809010/how-to-schedule-a-quartz-job-on-all-workers)

Comment: @Tomasz you are correct. I posted a comment on the other thread. Thanks.